# Upstart kills all process started by script

Tags: upstart, process

So I use Upstart `[myscript]` to start a script `[A]`, which starts another script `[B]`, which in turn starts some other scripts `[GROUP C]`.

When I run `stop [myscript]`, I encounter the unusual behavior where `[GROUP C]` is also stopped. Every script in `[GROUP C]` has been started with a `&`, and are running in the background. I am surprised that they are also killed by the `stop [myscript]` command. Why is this, and how to I prevent it from happening?

EDIT: Basically `[myscript]` is as follows:

```
pre-start script
          echo 'Starting myscript Daemon\n'
end script

script
        exec /foo/bar/myscript-start.sh
end script

post-stop script
        echo 'and apparently we are done....'
end script
```

Answer (score 2):

Upstart [kills the process group](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/):

> The signal specified by the kill signal stanza is sent to the process
>   group of the main process. (such that all processes belonging to the
>   jobs main process are killed). By default this signal is SIGTERM.

To avoid this, start the child processes in a new session with `setsid`, for example:

```
setsid top
```

ps (`ps -eo '%c %a %p %P %r'`) will show that the process has a unique process group, and a parent pid of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you don't understand how scripts stanzas works.

### pre-start stanza

```
pre-start script
          echo 'Starting myscript Daemon\n'
end script
```

This script start before your main scrips, if it fails, the start sequence will fails. This is normally used for some adhoc operations that will allow the first script to start, these are not daemon-like (continuously running at background). Example:

```
pre-start script
    /lib/init/apparmor-profile-load usr.sbin.avahi-daemon
end script

script
    opts="-D"
    [ -e "/etc/eucalyptus/avahi-daemon.conf" ] && opts="${opts} -f /etc/eucalyptus/avahi-daemon.conf"
    exec avahi-daemon ${opts}
end script
```

As you can see, the apparmor profile is first load from the DBus (yeah, kind of awkward if you don't know the backend of Ubuntu) then starts the service as intended. This operation is designed for process that die once executed.

### script stanza

```
script
        exec /foo/bar/myscript-start.sh
end script
```

This is the only part of your program that needs to run continuously and upstart has to track it's PID. This process dies when you stop the script.

### post-stop stanza

```
post-stop script
        echo 'and apparently we are done....'
end script
```

This stanzas are designed as a kind of a cleanup process. It will be executed once the main script dies gracefully. For example, apport:

```
post-stop script
    # Check for a hung resume.  If we find one try and grab everything
    # we can to aid in its discovery
    if [ -e /var/lib/pm-utils/status ]
    then
        ps -wwef > /var/lib/pm-utils/resume-hang.log
    fi

    if [ "`dd if=/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern count=1 bs=1 2>/dev/null`" != "|" ]
    then
        exit 1
    else
        echo 0 > /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
        echo "core" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
    fi
end script
```

It tries to detect a resume from sleep that was not successful and starts preparations for detect the next hang so it can produce a useful report (yeah, is complicated again, but that was the most simple script I found apart `ufw` which is oversimplified). As you can see each process dies by itself since it could block the shutdown of the system (in such cases there's also a script that sends `TERM` and `KILL` signals to hanged process).

Bottom line, what you are experiencing is perfectly normal and is the desired behavior of upstart.

Comment: I think we have a bad case of miscommunication. I get what the stanzas do (for the most part, anyway) and their intended use. That isn't my problem. My problem is that when I say `exec /foo/bar/myscript-start.sh`, `myscript-start.sh` in turn starts a process which in turn starts multiple background processes. When I use upstart to stop `myscript` (`stop myscript`), all the background processes are also stopped.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, upstart kills the parent process and all it's child/forks. I'll look for the documentation.

Comment: Reading the [cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id116), explaining the stop action, section 8 says "The signal specified by the kill signal stanza is sent to the process group of the main process. (**such that all processes belonging to the jobs main process are killed**). By default this signal is SIGTERM." You should edit your question with the content of the last comment so I can write that as answer.

Comment: This is valuable information and I would much appreciate it if you were to include it in your answer, but my actual question remains the same: "Why is this, and how to I prevent it from happening?" I figured upstart was killing the child group, I just don't know the reasoning or how to stop it from happening.

Comment: @MirroredFate if you edit your question with the contents of your first comment I will edit it. Going from your question to my answer without reading the commends will result confusing (as you could notice by my first answer).

Comment: I literally just restated (part) my question in my first comment. My question does not need to be edited. I think you may want to re-read it.

Comment: I think the question of how to have it send `SIGTERM` **just to the process** instead of the whole group is not answered.  And that is what is the OP's issue here is it not?

Comment: Upstart and Systemd track which processes depend upon each other. Your upstart job requires myscript to be running for C to start. You must rewrite C's .init file to not depend upon myscript.

Comment: @user535733 if I'm not reading incorrectly, he's using upstart to start several scripts in succession, no jobs.

Comment: Ah, you're right, of course. Perhaps C should be a separate job started by myscript, so myscript and A and B can terminate.